# Serializing foreign key in Django rest framework (A->B->C)

Tags: nested, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

How do i serialize foreign key that already refers to a foreign key of another table. Currently I am having three tables A,B and C (A->B->C). A refers to B and B refers to C. I need to get JSON as shown below

```
A:
{
 A_id:1,
 A_name:'aaa',
 B:
 {
   B_id:1,
   B_name:'bbb'
   C:
   {
     C_id:1,
     C_name:'ccc'
    }
  }
 }
```

I am able to get the JSON for one reference. i.e; A->B
i used `RelatedField` and overrided `to_representation` function to achieve this. This is the code i used

```
class B_foreign(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value


class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    B = B_foreign(source='B_id', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now what will i do to refer 'C' from B ? Do another RelatedField class and override to_representation() function?
I tried that too. It didn't work. Can someone help me with solution?

Answer (score 0):

You just use the serializer for the given model:

```py
class CSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = '__all__'


class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    C = CSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = '__all__'


class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    B = BSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'
```